# Read xml as a string

Tags: c#, encoding

I have an xml file which i need to read and store it as a string.Below is my content in xml.

```
<list>
<SlideShow id="12523" languageadded="sv" publish="1">
 <name language="sv">Ann-Marie från SWE</name>
</SlideShow>
</list>
```

And i am using below code to read,

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fStream);
ItemController.cacheTG = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
fStream.Close();
```

But when i read tghe special character in the name field "Ann-Marie från SWE" converts to Ann-Marie fr?n SWE.
How to read the xml without changing special characters.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that actually uses XML. It's also not clear what encoding you're using - it's *implicitly* UTF-8, but I suspect that your file is *actually* broken, and written in a different encoding :(

Comment: And do you *have* to cache it as a string? It would be better if you could store it as raw binary data, and let the XML parser handle the encoding.

Comment: How are you determining that the string is `fr?n` are you seeing this is a text file or on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to encoding. You need to specify the encoding (UTF8) like this:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fStream, System.Text.UTF8Encoding);
ItemController.cacheTG = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
fStream.Close();
```

You can find out the possible samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That in itself won't help - because UTF-8 is the default if you don't specify an encoding.

Comment: Sure, that was an example... Probably a bad one!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what character encoding the file is using. Once you know that, you can use the two-argument constructor for `StreamReader`, which takes a character set. For example, if your file is UTF-8:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Your program will have to determine (through some other mechanism) somehow what encoding to use, if it's not known at compile time.